# CMake find_package dependency on subproject

Tags: cmake

I have the following directory layout:

```
main_folder
 + static_lib1
 + executable
```

- Both 'static_lib1' and 'executable' have a full CMakeLists so that they can be
  built independently.
- The 'executable' depends on 'static_lib1'. It uses `find_package()` to locate 'static_lib1'.
- The main_folder contains a CMakeLists that includes both 'static_lib1' and 'executable' via `add_subdirectory` for conveniently building the whole project in one go.

Everything works fine if I manually build 'static_lib1' and then 'executable'. But when running the CMakeLists from the main folder, I get an error because `find_package` is unable to find the library files from 'static_lib1' which have not yet been built.

How can I resolve this while keeping the CMakeLists files separate (i.e. without including the static_lib's CMakeLists from the executable's CMakeLists)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch from a file-based approach to a target-based approach for handling the dependency from `executable` to `static_lib1`.

The original problem occurred because `executable` called `find_package` for locating `static_lib1`, which then attempted to fill a variable like `STATIC_LIB1_LIBRARY`  with the paths to the library files by calling `find_library`. `executable` then consumes the content of that variable in a `target_link_libraries(executable ${STATIC_LIB1_LIBRARY})` call. The problem here is, since those library files only get generated as part of the build, that call to `find_library` will not be able to find anything.

Building `executable` needs to support two scenarios here:

1. Building standalone, where a pre-compiled version of `static_lib1` is located somewhere on the disc.
2. Building from `main_folder`, where both `executable` and `static_lib1` are part of the same build.

The approach from the question supports scenario 1, but not scenario 2.

Instead of using using a variable to communicate a dependency between the two builds, use a target. The `CMakeLists.txt` for `static_lib1` likely creates a library target like `add_library(static_lib1 [...])`. In executable we now simply do `target_link_libraries(executable PUBLIC static_lib1)`. This is sufficient to support scenario 2.

To also allow for scenario 1 at the same time, we look at the call to [`find_package(static_lib1)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) in the `CMakeLists.txt` for `executable`. Instead of providing a variable like before, this call now needs to provide a target `static_lib1` for consumption.

So we adapt the find script for `static_lib1` to the following behavior:

- If a target `static_lib1` already exists, there's nothing to be done and the find script can just return (this is scenario 2).
- Otherwise, we call [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) to locate the library file on disc (as before in the original approach) and then create a new imported target: `add_library(static_lib1 STATIC IMPORTED)`. We then configure all relevant properties of the static library to that target. For instance, to add the location of the library file, we could do

  ```
  set_target_properties(static_lib1 PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES "CXX"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${STATIC_LIB1_LIBRARY}
  )
  ```

  To support multi-config generators like MSVC, instead of setting [`IMPORTED_LOCATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) and [`IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES.html), you will want to set the configuration specific properties like [`IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG` and `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION_CONFIG.html) instead. Since this can get quite tedious to do manually, you can have CMake generate this information (and a bunch of other convenient stuff) for you in a [package script](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html). The find mechanism for package scripts works slightly different under the hood, but the code in the `CMakeLists.txt` for `executable` will look just the same, a simple call to `find_package(static_lib1)`. The main difference is that this call will then not dispatch to a hand-written find script, but to a package script that was automatically generated by CMake as part of the build process of `static_lib1`.

Answer (score 3):

In executable's CMakeLists.txt you can check if you are building stand-alone or as part of project:

```
if( CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR )
  # stand-alone build
  find_package(static_lib1)
else()
  include_directories(../static_lib1)
  link_directories(../static_lib1)
  ...
  target_link_libraries(executable static_lib1)
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks! This works quite nice with Makefiles, but I'm having trouble finding the right directories with MSVC. The different profiles (Debug/Release/etc) end up in different target directories and I could not find a reliable way to identify those. I tried using the debug/optimized qualifiers in target_link_libraries but they do not allow to discern e.g. between the Release and MinSizeRel profiles. Any suggestions what to do here?

Comment: This gets very hard to manage in large projects with lots of independent parts. Shouldn't I be able to create these sub-projects independently, and then have CMake figure out whether certain dependencies can be found on the system or just somewhere else in the "top-level" project? Your suggested method requires the sub-projects to know exactly where to find their dependencies in the "top-level" project, which they don't even know exists.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I will leave this answer for posterity since only recently I have searched for a solution to this problem and found out that...

#### Since CMake 3.24 it is possible!

It is possible to override subsequent calls to `find_package()` with `FetchContent_Declare()` flag **`OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE`**.

Your

```cpp
add_subdirectory("path/to/static_lib1")
```

call has to be replaced in `main_folder/CMakeLists.txt` with:

```cpp
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    static_lib1
    SOURCE_DIR "path/to/static_lib1"
    OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
)
```

Any calls to `find_package(static_lib1)` will call `FetchContent_MakeAvailable()` for you, virtually making it identical to `add_subdirectory()` call.

You can read more about `OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE` in [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#integrating-with-find-package).